# Sum of odd and even digits of a number using recursion

Tags: python-3.x

I have currently set a code that adds the even or odd digits of a number. But when I run it, it does not add all the digits.

I know that modulus (%) and float division (//) should be used, but I cannot go on further. I only want to use recursion and while loop, since I haven't yet learned for loop.

```
def sum_even_digits(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    remainder = number % 10
    if remainder % 2 == 1:
        return 0
    if remainder % 2 == 0:
        return number % 10 + sum_even_digits(number // 10) 

def sum_odd_digits(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    remainder = number % 10
    if remainder % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    if remainder % 2 == 1:
        return number % 10 + sum_even_digits(number // 10)
```

For instance, I expect the even digit sum of 256 is 8, but it only gives 6.

Comment: `//` is integer division, not float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in your second case, when the remainder is not the kind of number you want to sum, you should not return 0. Returning 0 would mean not checking the rest of the number, which could still contain even/odd digits. You should just ignore the remainder and continue to recurse:

```
def sum_even_digits(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    remainder = number % 10
    if remainder % 2 == 1:
        return sum_even_digits(number // 10) # note this line
    if remainder % 2 == 0:
        return remainder + sum_even_digits(number // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each digits.

Try this snippet in your function.

```
sum_even=0
sum_odd=0
number=123456789
while number!=0:
    rem=number%10
    If rem%2==0:
        sum_even=sum_even+rem
    else:
        sum_odd+=rem
    number=inte(number/10)
print("Sum of even digital is :", sun_even)
print("Sum of odd digital is :", sun_odd)
```